# svn can't co source code

Tags: macos, mac

OS X 10.9

```
➜  java  svn --version
svn, version 1.8.5 (r1542147)
compiled Nov 27 2013, 08:16:39 on x86_64-apple-darwin13.0.0

Copyright (C) 2013 The Apache Software Foundation.
This software consists of contributions made by many people;
see the NOTICE file for more information.
Subversion is open source software, see http://subversion.apache.org/

The following repository access (RA) modules are available:

* ra_svn : Module for accessing a repository using the svn network protocol.
  - with Cyrus SASL authentication
  - handles 'svn' scheme
* ra_local : Module for accessing a repository on local disk.
  - handles 'file' scheme
* ra_serf : Module for accessing a repository via WebDAV protocol using serf.
  - using serf 1.3.2
  - handles 'http' scheme
  - handles 'https' scheme

➜  java  svn checkout http://java-allocation-instrumenter.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ java-allocation-instrumenter-read-only
svn: E120108: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'http://java-allocation-instrumenter.googlecode.com/svn/trunk'
svn: E120108: Error running context: The server unexpectedly closed the connection.
```

Answer (score 6):

I had this issue after getting a new mac with OS X 10.9 and found that is was the WebSecurity module of Cisco AnyConnect 3.1 blocking the outbound traffic.

I used WireShark to sniff the checkout command, no packets to the subversion server were leaving my machine.

I checked Console.app and displayed were these messages each attempt to checkout:

```
acwebsecagent[pid]: Connection : Auth key is not provided or is invalid, applying connection failure policy. CMode : 0 TMode : 0
acwebsecagent[pid]: Connection : Auth key is not provided or is invalid, applying connection failure policy. CMode : 2 TMode : 1
```

acwebsecagent is the AnyConnect WebSecurity module. My company is not using this module anyway, so I decided to uninstall the module using the command

```
sudo /opt/cisco/anyconnect/bin/websecurity_uninstall.sh
```

The connection to subversion was restored instantly.

Answer (score 0):

try using:

```
svn co http://java-allocation-instrumenter.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/
```

In the event that doesn't work try putting `https://` instead of `http://`; if the issue persists you can clear out your known_hosts, as you may have a stale or invalid key.

Comment: not effect .it report same error